# Llenado de gridview con procedimiento de almacenado

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Estoy intentando  llenar una grilla con datos de un `sp` 
estoy trabajando con capa de datos , negocio y presentación

Aquí es donde hago el llamado a negocios y despues trae los datos desde la capa de datos (el `sp`)  `BuscarListaPersonal();` el `HTML` ya esta echo y adaptado.

Luego me tira este error al cargarlo:

> No se encontró ningún campo o propiedad `per_emp_per` en el origen de
>   datos seleccionado.

Pero ese campo si esta en mi `sp` y lo extraño es que ese es el ultimo campo de mi `sp`, que solo muestra datos (es un select), no tiene variables de entrada porsiaca

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using Negocio;
using System.IO;
using System.Data;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Text;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;

namespace Presentacion.Modulos.Mantencion
{
    public partial class Empleados_ADM : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        int Rut;
        string Apellido;
        int codsuc;
        int codemp;
        string CadenaConexion = MasterPage.CadenaConexion;

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                cargarDropEmpresa();
                cargarDropSucursal();
                BuscarListaPersonal();

                PanelMsje.Visible = false;
                GridP.Visible = true;
            }



            //Validacion de Usuario para mostrar contenido
            if (((string)Session["Tipo"]) == "1") // = Administrador
            {
                BuscarListaPersonal();
            }
            else
            {
                // si no es adminsitrador redireccionamos a la pagina principal
                ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Alert", "<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='javascript'> alert('No tiene permisos para este contenido!');  document.location=('/Modulos/Principal.aspx');</SCRIPT>");
            }
        }


        //------Carga el droplist 
        protected void cargarDropSucursal()
        {

            DataTable Sucursal = new DataTable();
            Sucursal = AccesoLogica.BuscarParametros_PorTabla(Convert.ToInt16(Session["Tab_Sucursales"].ToString()), CadenaConexion);
            DropSucursal.DataSource = Sucursal;
            DropSucursal.DataValueField = "PAR_COD_PAR";
            DropSucursal.DataTextField = "PAR_DES_PAR";
            DropSucursal.DataBind();
            Session["Codsuc"] = DropSucursal.SelectedIndex;
        }
        protected void cargarDropEmpresa()
        {

            DataTable Empresa = new DataTable();
            Empresa = AccesoLogica.BuscarParametros_PorTabla(Convert.ToInt16(Session["Tab_Empresas"].ToString()), CadenaConexion);
            DropEmpresa.DataSource = Empresa;
            DropEmpresa.DataValueField = "PAR_COD_PAR";
            DropEmpresa.DataTextField = "PAR_DES_PAR";
            DropEmpresa.DataBind();
            Session["Codemp"] = DropEmpresa.SelectedIndex;
        }

        //------Carga de gridView por sucursal o Apellido si apellido o rut esta vacío solo filtra por sucursal si no hay ninguna sucursal busca por todos
        public void BuscarListaPersonal()
        {

            GridP.DataSource = AccesoLogica.Buscar_Empleadosadmin(CadenaConexion);
            GridP.DataBind();



        }


        //------LLena la grilla dependiendo del codigo de sucursal extraido del droplist
        protected void DropSucursal_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            DropSucursal.SelectedIndexChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.DropSucursal_SelectedIndexChanged);
            Session["Codsuc"] = DropSucursal.SelectedIndex;
            //BuscarListaPersonal();
        }

        ////------LLena la grilla dependiendo del codigo de Empresa extraido del droplist //cswsawdadfawodiuhawdoihwdopadhopwid
        protected void DropEmpresa_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            DropEmpresa.SelectedIndexChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.DropEmpresa_SelectedIndexChanged);
            Session["Codemp"] = DropEmpresa.SelectedIndex;
            // BuscarListaPersonal();
        }



        ///-----------------------------Codigo Agregado EF
        ///-----Paginacón de la grilla
        protected void GridP_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
        {
            this.GridP.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
            // BuscarListaPersonal();    
        }

        //------Exportar el Informe de empleados
        protected void BtnInforme_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
        {
            //// Session["Suc"] = DropSucursal.SelectedIndex;
            Response.Redirect("~/Modulos/Mantencion/Informes/InformesEmpleados.aspx");
        }

        protected void GridP_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }


        //------Redireccionamiento a modulos de empleados por rut
        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtRut.Text) & String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtApellido.Text))
            //{
            //    PanelMsje.Visible = true;
            //    txtRut.Focus();
            //    return;
            //}
            //else if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtRut.Text))
            //{
            //    Rut = 0;
            //    Apellido = txtApellido.Text;
            //    txtApellido.Focus();


            //}
            //else if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtApellido.Text))
            //{

            //    Rut = Convert.ToInt32(txtRut.Text);
            //    Apellido = "null";

            //}

            //else if (txtRut.Text != null & txtApellido.Text != null)
           // {

                //Apellido = txtApellido.Text;
                //Rut = Convert.ToInt32(txtRut.Text);

                //        DataTable BuscarEmpleado = new DataTable();
                //        BuscarEmpleado = AccesoLogica.LLenarGrillaAdmin(Rut, Apellido, Codsuc, Codemp, CadenaConexion);
                //        GridP.DataSource = BuscarEmpleado;
                //        GridP.DataBind();
                //    }

                //    DataTable Buscar = new DataTable();
                //    Buscar = AccesoLogica.LLenarGrillaAdmin(Rut, Apellido, Codsuc, Codemp, CadenaConexion);
                //    GridP.DataSource = Buscar;
                //    GridP.DataBind();

                //    BuscarListaPersonal();
                //}
              //  {

                    string Rut = this.txtRut.Text.Trim();
                    string Apellido = this.txtApellido.Text.Trim();
                    string Codsuc = this.DropSucursal.Text.Trim();
                    string Codemp = this.DropEmpresa.Text.Trim();

                    if (Rut.Length == 0)
                        if (Apellido.Length == 0)
                            if (Codsuc.Length == 0)
                                if (Codemp.Length == 0)
                                {


                                    Rut = "";
                                    Apellido = "";
                                    Codsuc = "";
                                    Codemp = "";
                                    GridP.DataSource = AccesoLogica.LLenarGrillaAdmin(Convert.ToInt16(Session["Rut"].ToString()),
                                        (Session["Apellidos"].ToString()), Convert.ToInt16(Session["Codsuc"].ToString()),
                                        Convert.ToInt16(Session["Codemp"].ToString()), CadenaConexion);
                                    GridP.DataBind();
                                   // BuscarListaPersonal();

                                }
                }




            }
        }
```

mi procedure en ese campo tiene un inner join a una tabla padre que contiene todas las tablas y tiene como codigo 999 , vale decir que la tabla hija de ella tiene como codigo 999-1 que contiene por ejemplo las sucursales, la 999-2 tiene las empresas y asi sucesivamente. entonces mi sp cuando va a buscar algo de esa tabla  es asi :

```
Alter PROCEDURE [dbo].[IN_OBTENER_LISTADO_PERSONAL1]
AS
BEGIN
SELECT  per_rut_per, per_nom_per, 
        (per_ape_pat+' '+per_ape_mat) AS Apellidos,
        per_anx_per, 
        per_cor_ele ,
        par1.par_des_par as per_emp_per,
        par2.par_des_par as per_suc_per 
        FROM PER 
        INNER JOIN PAR as par1 ON PAR1.PAR_COD_TAB = 18  AND par1.PAR_COD_PAR = per_emp_per
        INNER JOIN PAR AS PAR2 ON PAR2.PAR_COD_TAB = 13  AND PAR2.PAR_COD_PAR = per_suc_per
```

si puedes apreciar el campo que me sale el erro esta siendo mostrado por el campo par_des_par  que trae el texto de cualquier campo puesto al final del inner y esta definido con el nombre correcto como se puede apreciar as per_emp_per
//*********************************************************
CAPA DE NEGOCIOS
  public static DataTable Buscar_Empleadosadmin(string CadenaConexion)
        {
            return AccesoDatos.Buscarlistado_EmpleadosAdmin(CadenaConexion);
        }
        public static DataTable LLenarGrillaAdmin(int Rut, string Apellido, int codsuc, int codemp, string CadenaConexion)
        {
            SqlCommand _comando = AccesoDatos.ListadoPersonalEmpresa(Rut, Apellido, codsuc, codemp, CadenaConexion);
            _comando.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            return AccesoDatos.EjecutarComando(_comando);
        }
    }
//***********************************************************
CAPA DE DATOS
  public static DataTable Buscarlistado_EmpleadosAdmin(string CadenaConexion)
        {

```
        SqlConnection Conexion = new SqlConnection(CadenaConexion);
        SqlCommand Comando = new SqlCommand("IN_OBTENER_LISTADO_PERSONAL1", Conexion);
        Comando.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        try
        {
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(Comando);
            DataTable Set = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(Set);
            return Set;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

//************************************************
CAPA DE DATOS, DONDE SE EJECUTA LO ANTERIOR(FUNCION QUE OCUPAN TODOS)

```
    public static DataTable EjecutarComando(SqlCommand _comando)
    {
        DataTable _tabla = new DataTable();
        try
        {
            _comando.Connection.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter _adaptador = new SqlDataAdapter();
            _adaptador.SelectCommand = _comando;
            _adaptador.Fill(_tabla);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            _comando.Connection.Close();
        }
        return _tabla;
    }
```

Comment: podrias poner el codigo donde ejecutas ese procedure ? o sea el codigo ado.net. Entiendo que usas un datareader para acceder a los campos, no?

Answer (score 1):

Codigo para el Evento de tu Botón

> Codigo para Mysql

```
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        MySqlCommand comando = new MySqlCommand("mi_procedimiento", conexion);
        comando.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        MySqlDataAdapter sda = new MySqlDataAdapter(comando);
        sda.Fill(dt);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

> Código para SqlServer

```
 DataTable dt = new DataTable();
 SqlCommand comando = new SqlCommand("mi_procedimiento", conexion);
 comando.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
 SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(comando);
 sda.Fill(dt);
 dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

> Ejemplo Select de un Procedimiento para Mysql

```
DELIMITER ;;
CREATE PROCEDURE `mi_procedimiento`()
BEGIN
select * from mitabla;
END ;;
DELIMITER ;
```

> Ejemplo de un Insert para Mysql

```
DELIMITER ;;
CREATE  PROCEDURE `proc_add_profesor`(
p_nuemp int,
p_nombre varchar(45),
p_apepat varchar(45),
p_apemat varchar(45),
p_direccion varchar(100),
p_telefono varchar(45),
p_correo varchar(45),
p_usuario varchar(45)
)
BEGIN
insert into mitabla values(p_nuemp,p_nombre,p_apepat,p_apemat,p_direccion,p_telefono,p_correo,p_usuario);
END ;;
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Esta claro que el mensaje de error indica que quieres obtener el valor del campo `per_emp_per` el cual no defines en el `SELECT` que retorna el procedure.

En el codigo que muestras no se visualiza la ejecucion del procedure, por lo tanto no es util para analizar el problema.

Lo que recomendaria es que evalues el SELECT que ejecutas y si los campos que este define coinciden con los que accedes desde codigo

Comment: mi procedure en ese campo tiene un inner join a una tabla padre que contiene todas las tablas y tiene como codigo 999 , vale decir que la tabla hija de ella tiene como codigo 999-1 que contiene por ejemplo las sucursales, la 999-2 tiene las empresas y asi sucesivamente. entonces mi sp cuando va a buscar algo de esa tabla  es asi :